# How to access the variable/component name after assigning to a new variable

Tags: r, loops, lapply

How can I access the component names of a list inside a loop?

```
for(v in list(a=1, b=2)){
     paste(variable_name(v),"is",v)
     ## to print a is 1 and b is 2
}
```

I know the following code works but I guess there should be a better way:

```
 l <- list(a=1, b=2)
 for(vName in ls(l)){
      paste(vName, "is", l[[vName]])
 }
```

The same problem rises when using any other form of iteration over elements such as "apply" functions. How to access the component names without passing the list of names?

```
 sapply(function(x) paste(x_variable, "is", x), l)
```

Is there a way to access the names directly? If not, what is the best practice?
Thank you.

Comment: I did accept an answer today. Yesterday I could not. Thanks.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi that's actually frowned upon now (making help conditional upon acceptance). Users don't have to accept answers.

Comment: @AliKhosro Just FYI, but I looked and you haven't accepted any Answers yet - you need to click the big tick to accept. Note you don't have to accept anything, but as you indicated you had accepted an answer yet this doesn't show up I thought I'd mention it. See the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for example

Comment: Thanks. yes you were right. I had me confused. Now I did it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `names()`:

```
ll <- list(a=1, b=2)
for(v in seq_along(ll)){
     writeLines(paste(names(ll)[v], "is", ll[v]))
}

> ll <- list(a=1, b=2)
> for(v in seq_along(ll)){
+      writeLines(paste(names(ll)[v], "is", ll[v]))
+ }
a is 1
b is 2
```

Note now that I loop over an index of the elements of the list (which I assign as `ll` outside the loop), rather than the elements themselves. You also probably don't want to call `names()` many times, so you should outline that ahead of the loop too:

```
ll <- list(a=1, b=2)
nams <- names(ll)
for(v in seq_along(ll)){
     writeLines(paste(nams[v], "is", ll[v]))
}
```

Also, just on terminology, the things you are calling variables (`a`, `b`) aren't really variables *sensu* other programming languages. In R, `a` and `b` are the **components** of a list. I was a little confused as to what you wanted initially.

It's slightly tricker to do this with `sapply()`, but the same idea works: iterate over the indices of objects elements/components not the elements/components themselves.

```
sapply(seq_along(ll),
       function(i, list, names) paste(names[i], "is", list[i]),
       list = ll, names = nams)

> sapply(seq_along(ll),
+        function(i, list, names) paste(names[i], "is", list[i]),
+        list = ll, names = nams)
[1] "a is 1" "b is 2"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have two new questions: 
1) What if we have environment instead of list. The environment is not subsettable. 
2) What is the advantage of your solution to sapply(names(ll), function(x, list) paste(x, "is", list[x]), list=ll)?
Is your solution faster or more efficient?
Thank you.